# What is the maximum supported size of a truecrypt file?

Tags: security, backup, storage, encryption, truecrypt

What is the maximum size a truecrypt container can support? I'm trying to encrypt and store around 1TB data in a truecrypt container file. Is this a recommended usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"What is the maximum possible size of a TrueCrypt volume?

The maximum possible size of a TrueCrypt volume is 8589934592 GB. However, due to security reasons, the maximum allowed volume size is 1 PB (1,048,576 GB), as the amount of data that is considered secure to be encrypted using a single key depends, among other factors, on the block size of the encryption algorithm. In addition, you need to take into account other limiting factors. For instance, file system constraints, limitations of the hardware connection standard and of the operating system, etc."

From http://www.truecrypt.org/faq

Answer (score 2):

From the [FAQ](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq)

> The maximum possible size of a TrueCrypt volume is 8589934592 GB. However, due to security reasons, the maximum allowed volume size is 1 PB (1,048,576 GB), as the amount of data that is considered secure to be encrypted using a single key depends, among other factors, on the block size of the encryption algorithm. In addition, you need to take into account other limiting factors. For instance, file system constraints, limitations of the hardware connection standard and of the operating system, etc.

Further, I think since the encryption is working on the fly, larger volumes might be slower... no data there however.